# Web deployment task failed when using checksum

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, web-deployment

The following error appears in Visual Studio Professional 2013 Update 1 when I attempt to publish a project to my Release webserver.

> Error 2   Web deployment task failed. ((2/27/2014 9:21:20 AM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)
>
> (2/27/2014 9:21:20 AM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
>
> The method or operation is not implemented.
>
> at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.IncompleteParameterReplacementProvider.GetFilteredStream()
>
> at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObjectProvider.get_Checksum()
>
> at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncEquals(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject, Boolean skipKey)
>
> at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncDirPathChildren(DeploymentObject destRoot, DeploymentObject sourceRoot)
>
> at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncDirPathChildren(DeploymentObject destRoot, DeploymentObject sourceRoot)
>
> at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenNoOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>
> at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenNoOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>
> at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
>
> at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
>
> at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable'1 syncPassId, String syncSessionId)
>
> at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleSync(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData, Nullable1 passId)      0   0   MyWebsiteProject

Here is some background information.

1. Publish used to succeed on the Release environment until about a month ago. At that time I was using Visual Studio 2010. Upgrading to VS 2013 did not fix the problem.
2. Publish succeeds on my other two non-release environments and, note this, one of them *is on the same IIS/Windows Server as Release*.
3. Publish is using checksums using the "Set these properties for every profile in a given project" option as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/30/web-publishing-updates-for-app-offline-and-usechecksum.aspx).
4. Publish succeeds on my Release environment if I switch back to the File Time Stamp option. Sadly, time stamps are not a good solution since this project is supported by multiple developers using version control software.
5. I am currently working around the problem by manually copying changed files to the Release server.

Any ideas on how to get Publish working again?

**UPDATE ON 2014-03-19**

I tried to work around this problem by adding a new web site in IIS with the intention of replacing the existing, problematic one with a new one. The first publish worked but the same old error returned on the second publish. Apparently the problem is somewhere in the source code that is being deployed – perhaps in a Web.config XML transformation that is only being done on the Release server.

Answer (score 0):

Publish is once again working on my Release webserver. What follows are the steps that *may* have fixed the problem. (**DISCLAIMER:** I had not tried Publish for several weeks -- I had been deploying manually -- so it is possible that some previous, unknown change actually fixed Publish.)

1. Use Visual Studio's Publish Preview to generated a transformed **Web.config** (Found in project folder at ...\obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config on my computer).
2. Use a DIFF tool (I used [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)) to compare the Publish Preview **Web.config** to the Release webserver's **Web.config**.
3. Manually edit my **Web.config**, my **Web.Release.config**, and the webserver's **Web.config** to eliminate differences identified by the DIFF tool.
4. Repeat steps 1 through 3 until *all* differences (even white space) are eliminated.
5. Publish now works.